# pip install - running build_ext error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the dialogflow package in Pycharm virtual environment using pip:

```
pip install dialogflow
```

and it stops at this error:

```
running build_ext

error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

'Command "C:\Users\mclovine\PycharmProjects\sunshinveconv\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mclovine\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zotus0_t\\grpcio\\setup.py';f=getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mclovine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ub03a865\install-record.txt --si
ngle-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\mclovine\PycharmProjects\sunshinveconv\venv\include\site\python3.8\grpcio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mclovine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal
l-zotus0_t\grpcio\'
```

When I try the same installation in conda virtual environment, it works and there's no error.

I'm using: Windows64, Python 3.8.3, Visual C++ BuildTools 14.0

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: did the installation work though? or not?

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade to Python 3.7 works for me (ref: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1699#issuecomment-680807921)